# Speeding Up Complex php Function with Postgresql pgsql

Tags: php, database, postgresql, optimization

This is kind of a tough one as I don't know much about Postgresql's pgsql or C.

I'm hoping someone can get me started on this by laying out the basic control structure or suggest alternatives to the way I'm doing it in PHP to make this operation Faster.

Here's the Basic run-down. Code Below.

I have a row in an intake table, which may or may not match to an Existing Provider in my Normalized Database of Providers. I have varying Data elements, depending on the completeness of the row.

My Current Control Function Looks like this: It's job is to either return the ID of the existing provider, or create the new one then return that ID.

```
    function find_provider($input){
    if (!$by_i_id = $this->find_provider_with_i_provider_id($input->i_provider_id)){
        //Not By I ID
        if (!$by_medicare_id = $this->find_provider_with_medicare_id($input->national_provider_id)){
            //Not by Medicare ID
            if (!$by_license_number = $this->find_provider_with_license_number($input->license)){
                //Not by License Number
                if (!$by_s_id_map = $this->find_provider_with_s_provider_id($input->source_id, $input->s_client_id, $input->s_provider_id)){
                    //Not By S_id
                    if (!$by_tax_id = $this->find_provider_with_tax_id($input->tax_id, $input->s_entity_type, $input->source_id, $input->last_name, $input->first_name)){
                        //Not by Tax Id
                        if (!$by_name = $this->find_provider_by_name($input->first_name, $input->last_name)){
                            //not by Name.
                            return $this->add_provider($input);
                        }else{
                            //At least 1 Name Match
                            if (count($by_name) == 1){
                                $by_name = $by_name[0]->provider_id;
                                if (!$by_address = $this->confirm_provider_by_address($input->address1, $input->zip, $by_name)){
                                    //Not a Match
                                    return $this->add_provider($input);
                                }else{
                                    return $by_name;
                                }
                            }else{
                                //More than 1 Match
                                $match = array();
                                Foreach ($by_name as $key => $row){
                                    If ($this->confirm_provider_by_address($input->address1, $input->zip, $row->provider_id) != FALSE){
                                        $match[] = $row->provider_id;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (count($match)> 0){
                                    return $match[0];
                                }else{
                                    return $this->add_provider($input);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        return $by_tax_id;
                    }
                }else{
                    return $by_s_id_map;
                }
            }else{
                return $by_license_number;
            }
        }else{
            return $by_medicare_id;
        }
    }else{
        return $by_i_id;
    }
}
```

In this, I attempt to Match first by an Internal ID, then a Medicare ID, then a License, then a Source ID, then a Tax ID, then by Name and Address.

Each One of these Functions Looks Like this: (The etype is an Entity Type which may or may not be present. And the Not This ID is because I run these functions a 2nd time after, looking for a secondary match, as sometimes they can be from 2 different providers Simultaneously).

```
    function find_provider_with_i_provider_id($provider_id, $etype = null, $notthisid=null){
    //Select from provider where 'id' == $provider_id
    if (is_int($provider_id)==true && $provider_id != 0){
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->from('list_provider');
        $this->db->where('id', $provider_id);
        if (!$etype == null){
            $this->db->where('entity_type_id', $etype);
        }
        if (!$notthisid == null){
            $this->db->where('id !=', $notthisid);
        }
        $result = $this->db->get();

        if ($result->num_rows == 0){
            return false;
        }elseif ($result->num_rows == 1){
            //Call The Result Function to Pull the Data as an Object.
            $out = $result->result();
            return $out[0]->id;
            //return true;
        }else{
            $out = $result->result();
            //$this->log_event('find_provider_with_i_provider_id','error', 'Multiple Results for an Internal Provider ID', $provider_id);
            return $out[0]->id;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is a lot of Database work and I have to process a lot of rows (35 Million in the intake table currently). So this is Super Slow.

I'm trying to figure out how to Either Structure this better in PHP, or more ideally I think, re-write this whole thing into pgsql so the db can have this all pre-planned and optimized.

The database is appropriately indexed I believe (all select and join elements) but to run these 35 million rows still winds up taking like 2 weeks.

Thoughts? Help?

Please let me know if you need more info or have any questions. The Database is pretty close to normalized, except where I had to duplicate one or two pieces of information for different use cases where a Join wouldn't have worked. It's basically a snowflake pattern.

Comment: Why don't you reverse the logic to somewhat like : ` if (! ... ){ return ...; } instead of having that nested if's? my full HD widescreen almost isn't capable to display your code on 1 screen

Comment: why don't you just do a single query with `OR`s?  and is that a hand-rolled ORM?  having your db connection also maintain a single effectively-global partial query doesn't seems like a great design; surely there are fine existing PHP ORMs

Comment: @Eevee Because I need to know how it matched, as they have weighted Priority. Is there an easy way to build that into a query with a conditional?

Comment: @Eevee Just figured out how to do that with a Case When Clause. Going to give it a shot!

Comment: get all the matches, then check how each matched in app code.  complex ordering is not something that comes naturally to relational algebra.

Comment: So where is the query? How is this related to the database?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this, where you the returned table is however many rows your filters returned, and columns for all the options on "how it [could be] matched". Your PHP would be responsible for determining the priority of how it was matched, but only one query and database round-trip would be required.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.function(
    IN  filter1                 integer,
    ...
    IN  filterN                 text
)
    RETURNS TABLE (
        id                      integer,
        reason1                     boolean,
        ...
        reasonN                     boolean
    )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $body$
        DECLARE
        BEGIN
            RETURN QUERY
                SELECT
                    id,
                    CASE
                        WHEN reason1Criteria THEN true
                        ELSE false
                    END AS reason1,
                    ...
                    CASE
                        WHEN reasonNCriteria THEN true
                        ELSE false
                    END AS reasonN
                FROM tables
                WHERE
                    t.column1 = filter1 AND
                    ...
                    t.columnN = filterN;
        END;
    $body$;
```